# Handling an OPTIONS request in a Keystone.js API

Tags: rest, keystonejs

I'm building an SPA with Aurelia backed by Keystone.

When POSTing from my Aurelia view, the `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`, which of course, incurs an `OPTIONS` request when coming from the client-side.

My Keystone init settings are wide open on cors for local development:

```
keystone.init({
    ...
    'cors allow origin': true,
    'cors allow methods': true,
    'cors allow headers': true,
    ...
});
```

My Keystone route bindings for the API are:

```
exports = module.exports = function(app) {
    app.all('/api/*', keystone.middleware.cors);
    app.post('/api/inquiry', keystone.middleware.api, routes.api.inquiries.post);
};
```

My Keystone API view is:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Inquiry = keystone.list('Inquiry');

exports.post = function(req, res) {

    var inquiry = new Inquiry.model({
        name: {
            first: req.body.name.first,
            last: req.body.name.last
        },
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        question: req.body.question
    });

    inquiry.save(function(error) {
        if (error) {
            return res.apiError(error);
        }

        return res.apiResponse({
            'inquiry': inquiry
        });
    });

};
```

The problem I'm having is that the OPTIONS request 404s instead of returning a 200.

Even if I manually handle the OPTIONS request and simply return a status of 200, the POST request doesn't follow the OPTIONS request. Am I mis-understanding the OPTIONS request lifecycle?

I've also tried passing in different content types like `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `text/plain` with data matching those formats, which don't cause the OPTIONS request, but Keystone isn't parsing the contents of those POSTs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I missed the part in the Keystone documentation where you can customize the Express instance *before* you hand it to Keystone.

```
// keystone.js

var keystone = require('keystone');
var express = require('express');
var cons = require('consolidate');
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.text());

keystone.app = app;
```

Then in my Aurelia app, I call `JSON.stringify(myObject)` before POSTing it to Keystone. Subsequently in my Keystone view, I just have to parse the string back to JSON:

```
exports.post = function(req, res, next) {

    if (!req.body) {
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }

    var data = JSON.parse(req.body),
        inquiry = new Inquiry.model(data);

    inquiry.save(function(error) {
        if (error) {
            return res.apiError(error);
        }

        return res.apiResponse({
            'inquiry': inquiry
        });
    });

};
```